# Problems with the Featured Image Size in Wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, image

[This is the website where I'm trying the featured image on.](http://demilovatoonline.com/danithemes/) The site uses wordpress. As you can see, the Image uses a custom size, not the size I want it to use. Besides, it applies to itself the .post img { } characteristics. Here you have the codes I use.

(In PHP functions):

```
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' ); set_post_thumbnail_size(640,205);
```

And then, in HTML

```
<?php the_post_thumbnail();?>
```

I wrote down the  image size I wanted in the PHP Functions code, but it's not working! What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You could just set the image size when your using it, in the html, like this:

```
   <?php
   if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
        set_post_thumbnail_size( 640,205 );
        echo get_the_post_thumbnail( ); 
   }
   ?>
```

If you want to set custom values for the thumbnails in your functions.php file, you will have to do something like this:

```
 function mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size(){
    add_image_size( 'thumb-small', 200, 200, true ); // Hard crop to exact dimensions (crops sides or top and bottom)
    add_image_size( 'thumb-medium', 520, 9999 ); // Crop to 520px width, unlimited height
    add_image_size( 'thumb-large', 720, 340 ); // Soft proprtional crop to max 720px width, max 340px height
 }
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_custom_thumbnail_size' );
```

Comment: Do you have a feactured image in the post?

Comment: Yes, but it's shown in a custom size. You can see it here: demilovatoonline.com/danithemes

Comment: share the code of the file that is generating the posts list

Comment: This is the 'Main Index Template' Code (http://pastebin.com/kx7C23Em); This is the 'Theme Functions' Code (http://pastebin.com/JkLVd03n); And this is the code that defines the style of the Featured Image (http://pastebin.com/yFRfMnjk)

Comment: I'm not seeing all the code i need.. but already know another way to get it done.. Add: 

   .post img {
       witdh: 640px;
   }

to your css file, and you get the result you want..

Comment: Buth with width: 470px; it looks mutch better ;)